# Pandas - Create a binary column that returns True if a True is present in at least one out of two different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (enct) with two binary columns (008.45 and a04.7) and I would like to create a third column name "cdi" that would return True if there is at least one true in one of those two columns. Here's an example depicting the desired results:

```
008.45      a04.7       cdi
True        False      True
False       False      False   
False       True       True
```

Here is the code that I have tried:
`enct["cdi"] = enct.apply(lambda x: True if x == "True" in (x['008.45'], x["a04.7"]) else False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OR operator(`|`)

```
enct['cdi'] = enct['008.45'] | enct['a04.7']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `df.any()`:

```
df[['008.45','a04.7']].any().any()
```